# Error deployment with XmlSerializers assembly in Database project

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

In a VS2010 Database projet, I have a reference to a CLR project "MyProject" which use the build option "Generate serialization assembly". So, a generation of MyProject generates MyProject.dll and MyProject.XmlSerializers.dll.

When I choose "Deploy" on my database project, I have this error :
MyDatabase.dbschema(0,0): Error TSD00562: If this deployment is executed, [MyProject.XmlSerializers] will be dropped and not re-created.

How to fix this error ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

solution is a set of Visual C # SQLCLR Database Project,
on the Build property "Generate Serialization assembly" to "ON"
see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kb4wyys2(v=vs.100).aspx.
Regards Laco.

Answer (score 0):

In my example assemblies names are CallWorkflowServiceCLR.dll and CallWorkflowServiceCLR.XmlSerializers.dll

I create and share folder "D:\CLRProcedure" on destination server ("my_server_name") specially for deployments.

In Visual Studio in Project properties / Build events / Post-build event command line - I wrote: 
    xcopy /Q /Y "$(TargetDir)*.dll" "\my_server_name\CLRProcedure\"

Then in PostDeployScript.sql wrote:

```
if exists (select * from sys.assemblies 
where name = 'CallWorkflowServiceCLR.XmlSerializers')
DROP ASSEMBLY [CallWorkflowServiceCLR.XmlSerializers]

CREATE ASSEMBLY [CallWorkflowServiceCLR.XmlSerializers] 
from 'D:\CLRProcedure\CallWorkflowServiceCLR.XmlSerializers.dll'
```

P.S.: in my project's properties:

```
Build / Generate serialization assembly = ON
Database / Permisssion level = EXTERNAL
```

Also, you should start Visual Studio from user account that have rights to work with destination server